# How to force r-mapview to show all data on popup or certain rows, regardless of zcol=

Tags: r, r-leaflet, r-mapview

I'm trying to do a heatmap with R-mapview. I have spatialpolygondata with postcode areas. The problem is the data shown on the clickable popup, for example if I define zcol=("variable1") the popup shows all data (all in all 15 rows). The problem occurs when I define 2 or more columns on zcol, for example mapview(map, zcol=c("variable1", "variable2", "variable3", Legend=T), now the popup shows only the values for variables 1 to 3. Is there a way to force the popup to contain all the data which is linked to the specific area?

Comment: You need to create the popup content outside the mapview call. `pop = popupTable(map)` and then `mapview(map, zcol=c("variable1", "variable2", "variable3"), Legend=T, popup = pop)` should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got this figured out, and it turns out you can define the popup inside the mapview call as well, using popup = popupTable().

Comment: Good to know, I never tested that :-)